# How to close a connection using PrincipalContext to a remote host?

Tags: c#, active-directory, connection

When I execute this code,

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Machine, 
    computer.Name, 
    null,
    ContextOptions.Negotiate,
    Settings.UserName, 
    Settings.UserPassword))

GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
    oPrincipalContext, 
    Settings.AdministratorsGroup);
```

the connection to remote machine is created. I am able to see it writing "net use" in cmd.exe.

But I don't know how to close this connection before closing my app.

It automatically close when I exit from my app.

Here is my method:

```
public Dictionary<Principal, ComputerPrincipal>
GetMembersOfAdministratorsGroup(ComputerPrincipal computer)
{
    var usersList = new Dictionary<Principal, ComputerPrincipal>();
    var tempUsersList = new Dictionary<string, Principal>();

    using (PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = 
        new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.Machine, 
            computer.Name, 
            null,
            ContextOptions.Negotiate,
            Settings.UserName, 
            Settings.UserPassword))
    {
        using (GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal =
            GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                oPrincipalContext, 
                Settings.AdministratorsGroup))
        {
            if (oGroupPrincipal != null)
            {
                var result = oGroupPrincipal.GetMembers();
                foreach (Principal user in result)
                {
                    if (!tempUsersList.ContainsKey(user.Name))
                    {
                        tempUsersList.Add(user.Name, user);
                        usersList.Add(user, computer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return usersList;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the connection being open?

Comment: When I change userName and UserPassword, i can't connect to the remote machine, because I have the error: Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Both `PrincipalContext` and `GroupPrincipal` implement `IDisposable`. Make sure you dispose of them immediately after using them (and certainly before trying to connect again). This should remove the problem. E.g.

in shorthand:-

```
using(PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, computer.Name, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate, Settings.UserName, Settings.UserPassword))
using(GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, Settings.AdministratorsGroup))
{
    // perform operations here
}
```

or in longhand:-

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, computer.Name, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate, Settings.UserName, Settings.UserPassword);
try
{
    GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, Settings.AdministratorsGroup);
    try
    {
        // perform operations here
    }
    finally
    {
        oGroupPrincipal.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    oPrincipalContext.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You called Dispose on both oPrincipalContext and oGroupPrincipal?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a place elsewhere in your code which is doing something similar? If you make sure that all your disposal objects are disposed as soon as they are finished with then you shouldn't be seeing this problem. Unless, of course, the implementations of PrincipalContext and GroupPrincipal are flawed, but a I would guess a quick Google search would prove or disprove this.

Comment: I debugged my code. And the error occurred in second string of my code. But I sure that something i forgot to dispose, because when i exit the app all connections are closed.

Answer (score 0):

PrincipalContext is IDisposible.  Did you try calling Dispose or putting your code in a using block?

Comment: I called Dispose method. But nothing happened.